# exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Rename package'

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

This refactoring function in Eclipse for package names used to work for me fine until... today:

This is the first time I am receiving this weird Refactoring error, and I have no idea what to make of it:

> An exception has been  caught while
>   processing the refactoring 'Rename
>   Package'.
>
> Reason: Problems encountered while
>   moving resources.
>
> Click 'Undo' to undo all successfully
>   executed changes of the current
>   refactoring. Click 'Abort' to abort
>   the current refactoring.

What could possibly explain this sudden "change of heart" and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps something about your project is corrupted.  Have you tried shutting down Eclipse and starting it, and trying again?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Yes, I did try shutting down Eclipse and starting it, even before posting my request for help. I am totally baffled by this unpredictable behavior of one of the best tools on planet Earth. I even tried cleaning the entire project and building it - to no avail. The funny thing is that the project build and runs perfectly! It's only **package name** refactoring that stopped working for some reason. This is weird. Thanks & + 1 for your attempt to help.

Comment: You were lucky. Instead of Abort I have a Details button in Eclipse Mars (4.5.1), so only some of the changes were made, and my project is broken.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems from your snapshot that you are running windows 7, maybe vista. If its not a renaming issue, try running eclipse as administrator. It might be permissions-related, but its just a thought.

I see merit behind what Kurru is saying. Windows is not a case-sensitive operating system, meaning that is sees the words Cat and cat as the same thing. When you rename your package, Eclipse creates new directories/folder to put the package in. If you changed the case of your words and not actually rename it, it could throw this error.

Comment: Thank you too (and +1) for your insights. Yes, it's Windows 7 64-bit but refactoring package names used to be working perfectly! (up until now). I trust what @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen is saying, but re-installing Eclipse or pointing to a new workspace is not a correct solution IMHO - even if it makes the problem "disappear".

Comment: I solved the problem! It turns out that one .java file (only) was renamed recently in a manner that created the same type of aliasing Kurru & you were describing. I had to shutdown Eclipse, rename the file manually to match Java rules for matching filename with class, then everything started working as always again. I can only accept one answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Under Windows this is frequently caused by a file or directory being locked.  There can be several reasons for this:

- A file is open in a viewing program outside of Eclipse.  Windows will not allow the open file to be refactored.
- A CMD.EXE is active in one of the directories to be refactored.  Windows will not allow the directory to be moved or deleted.
- A program is running with open files for items in the workspace.  Windows will not allow the items to be refactored.

If this is the behaviour of a freshly started Eclipse on a freshly started machine, it is probably not Windows, but a corrupted workspace or Eclipse distribution, and you should unpack a fresh Eclipse and create a new workspace in which you can import (and *copy*) the existing projects from the old workspace.  I don't think this is the problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for your well thought answer. I just restarted Windows to see if this solves the problem. It didn't. Eclipse works perfectly in all other respects, so I don't think it's a corrupted Eclipse. Workspace has 0 (zero) errors. What else could this be? Thanks & +1.

Comment: As long as you have not tried the steps I list, I do not have other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just trying to rename a package to the same name, only with a different case, this error is thrown for me. Very annoying when trying to fix package names to the lowercase convention.

Had some success renaming packages to a step folder, then to the target folder...

ie.

APackage -> apackage   **FAIL**

APackage -> APackage2 -> apackage **SUCCESS**

Comment: Thanks + 1. I was NOT trying to rename the package to the same name with a different case. But... it was a .java file that had the same exact issue. (see my replay to Warlock).

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error. It turns out that my ClearCase (version control) plugin was inactive. Simply activated the version control plugin, and the problem was solved.

Comment: I just had the same problem with Subversion – the new location was not yet under version control, while the old one was. Thanks for your answer, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused if using characters like underscores in your class names (e.g. My_Class.java).  The project will build and run fine.  But in Eclipse, if you run Android Tools > Rename Application Package, the rename will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Same refactoring problem occurred to me when I was working in the Ubuntu. The cause is the permission limitations. Eclipse cannot re-factor as it does not have permission. After giving root permission, refactoring worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the problem because of case. I have successfully tried a solution.

1. This will fail

org.xyz.fileName ---rename---> org.xyz.filename

2. This will pass

org.xyz.fileName ---rename---> org.abc (rename the structure)

org.abc ---rename---> org.xyz.filename 
This will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I just restart the computer and start STS(Spring Tool Suite 4)
and delete the file/class its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder location is open in the Command prompt. If yes, then close it and try again.